# In Phase 10, what happens when a skip card is played by the only person who hasn't been skipped yet?

Tags: phase-10

In Phase 10, each player can only be skipped once per round. What happens if a player discards a skip card, but they are the only player who hasn't been skipped yet that round? Do they have to skip themselves since there is no one else to skip, or is the skip voided and considered just a normal discard?

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to have all the other players under pending skips when you take your turn. Someone may have been skipped (and are no longer under a pending skip) and can therefore be skipped again, though. There's always a valid target.

For example: the player to your right is a valid target. Even if they had just lost their turn to a skip, having lost their turn, they're no longer under a pending skip, so you can play a skip and select them to lose their *next* turn. They still will only lose one turn that round, as well. That is: no one else can play another skip on them until they pass their turn in the play order.

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_10) confirms this reading:

> A player cannot be skipped twice in the same round; **they must lose turn in the round before being skipped again. (They can be skipped twice in a row but not until they miss their turn.)**

As do [the rules on the designer's page](https://www.kenjohnsonspeaks.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Phase-10-Masters-Edition.pdf)

> If a player uses a “Skip” card against another player,
> no other player can use another “Skip” card against that player until that player’s turn has
> been skipped.

Comment: This doesn't line up with the way I read the rules... it says that a person can only be chosen for a skip once per round; not that a person can only be chosen for a skip if they don't already have a "pending" skip. The rules don't seem to make any distinction between a "pending skip" and a "skip that has happened this round". So in a 5 player game, if A takes his turn and skips B, then B should be safe from being chosen until A's next turn.

Comment: Yeah, I see that by your answer. But it is the way the rules read. Wiki agrees: "A player cannot be skipped twice in the same round; **they must lose turn in the round before being skipped again. (They can be skipped twice in a row but not until they miss their turn.)**"

Comment: Interesting... I'm reading the rules from [here](http://www.tactic.net/site/rules/FIN/03140.pdf)... I don't know if Wiki is going off of a different version of the rules; or just a different interpretation of "one per round".

Comment: That reads (or can be read) the same. "Only one “Skip” card against each player per “round” may be used."  Meaning two players can't skip player X between player X's turn in the rotation (a round). And it is the most common form of the rule ("Can't skip a player waiting to be skipped") across all games that I know.

Comment: So the [Phase 10 Wiki](https://phase10.fandom.com/wiki/Main_Rules#:~:text=A%20player%20may%20only%20be,up%20from%20the%20discard%20pile.) actually agrees with my interpretation; even using the same example I just did. But a couple other sites, including unorules.com, don't even mention the once per round restriction.

Comment: I checked a bit more and found that the designer, Ken Johnson, has a PDF of the rules on his page that are explicit in the reading as well.

Comment: Are you talking about [this page](https://www.kenjohnsonspeaks.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/PHASE-10-Card-Game-Instructions.pdf)? It looks like the same wording as the other PDF from tactic.net.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110571/discussion-between-l-scott-johnson-and-gendoikari).

Answer (score 3):

You may be misunderstanding the once per round restriction. From the rules:

> When someone is skipped, a “round” is once around the table.

So a “round” is not a hand; which ends when a player goes out. It is simply one turn for each player. So if it is your turn, there must be at least one other player who has not been skipped since your last turn.